Texture painting
i am having some issues with texture painting.
I guess it's about the project, because when i open up a new project it's working, but when i try on my wip project there is no way that i can texture paint.
I tried 1000 ways, i watched every tutorials on youtube about this but still cannot find to figure out how to actually paint on a surface.
Is someone else having the same problem?
How could i solve this?
I tried to export a single element as a fbx. and put on a new project and still not working.

Hello please share your file, remove all the useless objects: https://blend-exchange.com/
